# Why is my UiApp failing to display widgets when called by other users?

Tags: google-apps-script

When a user deletes a value from a spreadsheet cell that contains a note I want to display a UiApp.

An onEdit trigger is set on the following function:

```
function showDialogue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getValue() != '') return;
  if (r.getValue() == '' &&  r.getComment() != '') {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication();

    var label = app.createLabel('If you can see this, it has worked correctly.');
    app.add(label);

    var button = app.createButton('Click to Close');
    app.add(button);

    var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
    handler.addCallbackElement(label);
    button.addClickHandler(handler);

    r.setValue(r.getRow());

    ss.show(app);
  }

}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

It works fine when I do it but if another user has the spreadsheet open the UiApp fails to display properly. The UiApp window opens but no widgets are displayed and a Save As dialogue box opens prompting the user to save a userAppPanel.

I've replicated the problem in [this simplified spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/ahrosters.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ahyb6KRL_mwrdGZPekpTWnZIOTdTeVhLaDdzTVYtcVE#gid=0) that is shared with anyone who has the link (Can Edit).

Comment: It sounds like you should report this on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). By the way, you've forgot to past the link to the spreadsheet you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Henrique, I've put the link in now.

Comment: I think I've heard something like that before and it was happening only on Firefox... do you use Firefox too ? I can't remember right now the details but I'll try to search deeper :-)

Comment: It happened on both chrome and firefox to me (I'm on linux)

Comment: Right indeed, I tested a bit further and I'm pretty sure it's the result of the combination of the onEdit trigger and any UI... seems to be a real issue for the issue tracker ;)

Comment: @Henrique Abreu, Many thanks for trying out the spreadsheet. I've raised it in the issue tracker: [Issue 1991](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1991&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Comment: @Sergeinsas, Many thanks for trying out the spreadsheet. I'm using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m, OS is Windows Vista. I'm developing a system for rostering staff. The weird thing is that I already use onEdit tiggers to call UIs that still work (whew! I was scared to even look - the thought of re-doing all that work!), I can't figure out why this one doesn't. I've raised it in the issue tracker: [Issue 1991](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1991&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Comment: @fullofgas interesting info...thanks. Could you post a script that works with UiApp combined with onEdit,?  Every test I made failed... thanks

Comment: @Sergeinsas, It turns out I was wrong. All the Uis that work are called by onEdit events not installed onEdit triggers so there's nothing worthwhile to share, sorry.